# I want to convert text into speech in c# how can i so this please help me in detail . i m new in C#

Tags: c#

I want to make application that convert text to speech ... i m confused how to integrate Speech SDK .  can any one help on this . i want detail explanation . I m new in C# . How can i start this project ??

Any help will be appreciated ..

thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

Check out "[Programming Speech in WPF - Speech Synthesis](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/SpeechWPF09302008223352PM/SpeechWPF.aspx)" from 2008. A tutorial creating a WPF application using the Speech SDK.

It should get you started.